# How i can detect the overflow of Gzip and Bzip2 files during writing?

Tags: php, streaming, gzip, bzip2

I need to determine that the file exceeds the specified size while it is being written.
When i reach the specified size, i must stop writing and throw a exception.

Example for a normal file:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'wb');
while (true) {
    // its work
    if (fstat($handle)['size'] + strlen($string) > BYTE_LIMIT) {
        throw SizeOverflowException::withLimit(BYTE_LIMIT);
    }

    fwrite($this->handle, $string);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Or i can independently count the used bytes

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'wb');
$used_bytes = 0;
while (true) {
    if ($used_bytes + strlen($string) > BYTE_LIMIT) {
        throw SizeOverflowException::withLimit(BYTE_LIMIT);
    }

    fwrite($this->handle, $string);
    $used_bytes += strlen($string);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Example write Gzip:

```
$handle = gzopen($filename, 'wb9');
while (true) {
    // not work
    // fstat($handle) === false
    //if (fstat($handle)['size'] + strlen($string) > BYTE_LIMIT) {
    //    throw SizeOverflowException::withLimit(BYTE_LIMIT);
    //}

    gzwrite($this->handle, $string);
}
gzclose($handle);
```

Similarly for Bzip2:

```
$handle = bzopen($filename, 'w');
while (true) {
    // not work
    // fstat($handle) === false
    //if (fstat($handle)['size'] + strlen($string) > BYTE_LIMIT) {
    //    throw SizeOverflowException::withLimit(BYTE_LIMIT);
    //}

    bzwrite($this->handle, $string);
}
bzclose($handle);
```

I understand why `fstat()` does not work in this case, but how can i solve this problem?

Now i can calculate only how many bytes will be used in uncompressed mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead compress incrementally in memory using `deflate_init` and `deflate_add`, using the encoding `ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP`, and write the compressed data out normally with `fwrite`. Then you can count the compressed bytes written and stop at your specified size.

Comment: **Great idea. Thanks.** Unfortunately, i need support PHP 5.6 and still need Bzip2(((